# DroboS causes Windows Server 2008 box to hang on boot

Tags: windows-server-2008, drobo, esata, direct-attached-storage

I'm running a DroboS connected via eSATA and the machine will not boot past the initial Windows graphic loading screen no matter how long I let it run.

Windows Server 2008 x86
connected via an IOgear 4-Port RAID 5 eSATA PCI Card [ GIC704SR5 ]

Comment: This link on Drobo's site points to a possible issue with Backup, but it does not seem to match my experience: http://support.datarobotics.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/163